# Return attribute as list of case class

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Lets say I have

```
case class Foo(_id: BSONObjectID, bars: Set[Bar])
case class Bar(_id: BSONObjectID, name: String)
```

How can I get the `bars` of a specific `Foo` using projections?

I tried (omitting the declaration of the handlers)

```
val bars: Future[Option[Set[Bar]]] = fooes.find(
  BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONObjectID("specificId")), // Match condition
  BSONDocument("_id" -> 0, "bars" -> 1)              // Projection
).cursor[Bar]().collect[Set]()
```

But it doesn't work.

Regards

Comment: If you consider each document only for its `bars` field being a `Set[Bar]`, the cursor is not a `Bar` one, but a `.cursor[Set[Bar]]` and so you have to have a `BSONReader` available in the scope.

Comment: @cchantep I have tried that, but I obtain `could not find implicit value for parameter reader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[Set[Bar]]`. Am I missing an import?

Comment: @cchantep I omitted in the description the following (which I think it is obvious, but maybe it is not) `implicit val bsonF = Macros.handler[Bar]`.

Comment: There is no standard `BSONReader` provided by `Set` (as it can be unsafe), so either you go through `List` or you implemented your own `Set` reader.

Comment: @cchantep Sorry, but it is not working yet :( `could not find implicit value for parameter reader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[List[Bar]]`.

Comment: There is no `BSONDocumentReader` provided for such edge case. You have to implement your own `implicit def myEdgeReader(implicit br: BSONReader[_ <: BSONValue, Bar]): BSONDocumentReader[Set[Bar]] = new BSONDocumentReader[Set[Bar]] { def read(d: BSONDocument): Set[Bar] = d.asTry[List[Bar]]("bars").map(_.toSet).get } }`